# Can i use this JS code for Google adsense

Tags: javascript, adsense

I see this type of JS codes on so many website for Google adsense ad units.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Adsense Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
google_ad_type     = 'text';
google_gl          = 'default';
google_kw          = 'vps';
google_kw_type     = 'broad';
google_ad_client   = 'ca-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
google_ad_output   = 'js';
google_adtest      = 'on';
google_feedback    = 'on';
google_language    = 'en';
google_encoding    = 'utf8';
google_max_num_ads = '20';
function google_ad_request_done(google_ads)
{
var s = '';
var i;
for (i=0;i<google_ads.length;++i)
{
s += '<div class="gad-slot"><pre>';
s += '<a href="'+google_ads[i].url+'" target="_blank"><strong>'+google_ads[i].line1+'</strong></a><br />';
s += google_ads[i].line2+ '<br />' + google_ads[i].line3+'<br />';
s += '<small>' + google_ads[i].visible_url + '</small></pre></div>';
}
document.write(s);
return;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want also use this type of code on my site.

Please tell me is legal or illegal for Google adsense policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use this code because it is for premium publisher only

https://www.google.com/adsense/premium-login